# How can i check for valid fingerprint and no finger detected?

Tags: arduino-uno, adafruit

i am working in arduino fingerprint sensor with adafruit. i am using two leds to check if fingerprint is valid. my problem is that i need three cases instead of two.
1 case: when fingerprint is valid. turn on green led and turn off red led.
2 case: when fingerprint is not valid. turn on red led and turn off green led. i put a finger but was a not valid finger.
3 case: when there is no finger detected, turn off both leds.
Is there a way to do that?

i am using adafruit library and fingerprint sensor, with fingerprint.ino and using pin 11 and 12 for output.

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ... are you asking about turning on LEDs? ... or are you asking about reading fingerprints? ... the two things are not really related at all

Answer (score 1):

When there is no finger on the sensor, the function `Adafruit_Fingerprint.getImage()` from the Adafruit Fingerprint library returns the constant `FINGERPRINT_NOFINGER`. You can execute the function in a loop and setting the LED outputs in a `switch` statement according to the return value. Refer to the examples of the [Adafruit Fingerprint Sensor Library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Fingerprint-Sensor-Library). There you have directly the code for checking the sensor (since the full check for a valid fingerprint is longer than this one function call, you can use the `getFingerprintIDez()` function from the `fingerprint` example, or a variation of it).